# build ionic4 app for 64-bit missing 64-bit library

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having an application build in ionic 4. As google is changing his Google Play store policy for apk upload. I am having following query regarding it:-

1. How to built 64-bit apk for ionic and cordova application with crosswalk install into it.
2. do we need to two different apps with same or different android android-versionCode for release?

Comment: Are you up to date on all your cordova's dependencies ? 
By the way, are you sure you still need crosswalk in your app ?

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk is unmaintained for more than 3 years, and nowadays the webview is updated with the latest chrome. It's not advisable to increase the size 20MB and the complexity for a minor android versions.